# Calculating rolling standarddeviation in a grouped dataframe

Tags: r

I need a good way to run through a large dataframe and do calculations on a group.

this is my example data:

```
df_names <- data.frame()
for (int_x in 1: 1000)
  {
  df_names <- rbind( df_names, sample (c("John", "Peter", "Michael", "Lisa", "George", "Linda", 
 "Fresco", "Pope", "Niclas", "Rammen"),1)) 
}


 df <- data.frame(date= Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:5000, 1000)), 
                 score= runif(1000, min = 25, max=500),
                names= df_names)
```

Now i want to find the rolling standarddeviation for each name (ordered by date) i do this;

```
unique_names <- unique(df$names)
 for (int_y in 1:NROW(unique_names)){

  df %>% filter(names== unique_names[int_y]) %>%  arrange(date) %>% select( score)%>% as.matrix() %>% 
 rollapplyr( 5, sd, fill = 0)  }
```

Trouble1: How do i get the matrix back on the original dataframe?
Trouble2: This is a bad way of doing it, I think.. is there a tidy way of doing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calculating the rolling `sd` but quickly discarding it, which we can fix. Also, I think we can improve the flow of that to fully use tidyverse grouping, and keep everything together.

```r
set.seed(42)
df_names <- data.frame()
for (int_x in 1: 1000) {
  df_names <- rbind( df_names, name = sample (c("John", "Peter", "Michael", "Lisa", "George", "Linda",
 "Fresco", "Pope", "Niclas", "Rammen"),1))
}
df <- data.frame(date = Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:5000, 1000)),
                 score = runif(1000, min = 25, max=500),
                 name = df_names[[1]])
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 1000 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ date : Date, format: "2020-10-02" "2020-10-03" "2020-10-08" "2020-10-15" ...
#  $ score: num  285.1 343 41.7 78.7 351.7 ...
#  $ name : chr  "John" "George" "John" "Niclas" ...
```

The flow:

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(zoo) # rollapply
as_tibble(df) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(rollsd = zoo::rollapply(score, 5, sd, fill = 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice(100:120) # arbitrary, just to show the middle
# # A tibble: 21 x 4
#    date       score name   rollsd
#    <date>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
#  1 2022-02-22 365.  Niclas   74.7
#  2 2022-02-26 388.  George  107. 
#  3 2022-02-27 275.  Niclas   74.7
#  4 2022-03-05 171.  Rammen  158. 
#  5 2022-03-07 500.  Pope    150. 
#  6 2022-03-08 278.  Fresco   81.2
#  7 2022-03-11  37.7 Linda   204. 
#  8 2022-03-12  46.9 John    180. 
#  9 2022-03-13 224.  George  110. 
# 10 2022-03-16 302.  Niclas   63.4
# # ... with 11 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

with data.table:

```
df <- data.frame(date= Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:5000, 1000)), 
                 score= runif(1000, min = 25, max=500),
                 names= sample (c("John", "Peter", "Michael", "Lisa", "George", "Linda", 
                                  "Fresco", "Pope", "Niclas", "Rammen"),1000,replace=T))
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

result <- df[order(names,date)][, score_sd:=frollapply(score,5,sd) , by=.(names)]
head(result)
#>          date     score  names score_sd
#> 1: 2020-11-02  75.57479 Fresco       NA
#> 2: 2020-11-21 302.04435 Fresco       NA
#> 3: 2020-11-27  96.38495 Fresco       NA
#> 4: 2021-01-10 282.48808 Fresco       NA
#> 5: 2021-01-29 365.39886 Fresco 130.2117
#> 6: 2021-01-31 493.76108 Fresco 144.2819
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I reformated `df`, did you run the updated definition in my answer?